# adding two number formats together using javascript to return long number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a number with addition and javascript except the format of the numbers see to be a problem

```
var p ="89.43"
var a = "7,552.00"

var total = + parseInt(p) + parseInt(a);

//should return 7,641.43
console.log(total)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b127p6yu/

Comment: How can parse**Int** return `.43`?

Comment: you could add to your post the actual result, then we don't have to open the fiddle.

Comment: should return 7,641.43

Comment: @Blynn the "Int" in `parseInt()` means **integer**.

Comment: @Blynn you wrote th expected result, but not the current result

Comment: @Hacketo `parseInt("7,552.00")` will return `7`.

Comment: @Pointy not for me but for the readers

Comment: I can rename the question, sorry about that

Comment: And parseFloat('7,552.00') will also return 7

Answer (score 3):

Normalize your inputs (remove all commas) and use `parseFloat` method:

```
var num = parseFloat(p.replace(/,/g,'')) + parseFloat(a.replace(/,/g,''));
console.log(num); // 7641.43

var strWithCommas = num.toLocaleString();
console.log(strWithCommas); // 7,641.43
```

Comment: He may have to put the commas back in manually also, if he requires it.

Comment: @ManoDestra well if the OP wants numbers then putting commas back in doesn't really make much sense, but we don't know much about the OP's requirements :)

Comment: how would you put the commas back in?

Comment: @Blynn can you explain what it is you're trying to do? Numbers don't have commas in them; they're numbers. Why are you trying to convert the numeric strings to numbers? Are you trying to *verify* that they're valid numbers? Something else? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I was just trying to add two numbers together that are formatted differently

Comment: You need to remove the commas and parse them as floats. Then re add the commas, if you require to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` functions won't ignore commas. You can strip them out yourself before calling them:

```
a = parseInt(a.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));
```

Note however that *both* `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` will return a number if the input string simply *starts* with some valid numeric constant. A string like `"123hello world"` will be successfully parsed, in other words.

If you want a number with a fractional part, use `parseFloat()`; the `parseInt()` function specifically returns only integer values.